# How do I set up an android theme with different sizes of text?

Tags: android

I have been browsing around, in an attempt to understand android themes. I understand how to create and apply styles, unfortunately when it comes to themes, my brain just doesn't quite get it. Maybe it's because I come from a web-developer background, so my brain hasn't quite "re-wired" itself for android yet.

I'd like to do as little redundant work as possible, so i decided that my theme would have different text-sizes based on whether it's a header, a text-body or a small text(designer wants text to be bigger on some screen sizes). This way I can easily create different width-based layouts with different sizes of text depending on whether we are on a tablet or phone(instead of having to edit every single layout-file and TextView).

Can anyone help me understand how I should do this? The android developer's guide just confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can set up different styles in Android in your styles.xml file, if you wanted a different style for a title and header you would create two separate styles like so;

```
<style name="Title">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
</style>

<style name="Header">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout file you can use these styles like so;

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/Title" />
```

Or you can set a global style to all TextViews like so;

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Title</item> </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textAppearance item within your styles.xml like so;

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this applies to all text, doesnt it? If I want a different size for the header/title, what do I do then? 
Also i can't seem to find documentation on what the question sign means.